# Rails 4 assets issues

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently upgraded my app from rails 3 to rails 4.
All my stylesheets are in public folder. It needs to be in assets folder in rails 4. I am not sure how to move those. When I load my home those stylesheets are not been loaded. How can I get those stylesheets to be loaded.

```
Started GET "/stylesheets/%5B%22jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.21%22,%20%22/themes/circle/stylesheets/application%22,%20%22selectize%22,%20%22toggles-light%22,%20%22font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min%22%5D.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-02 17:32:05 +0530



  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/%5B%22jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.21%22,%20%22/themes/circle/stylesheets/application%22,%20%22selectize%22,%20%22toggles-light%22,%20%22font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min%22%5D.css")
```

I am getting same or similar message for each and every stylesheet.

Please help to fix this issue.

Comment: You need to move your stylesheets to assets/stylesheets directory. If you have already done that, then what kind of issue you're seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Just move the folders to `app/assets`, so you have `app/assets/images`, `app/assets/stylesheets` etc.  In dev mode, `image_tag` etc will look in app/assets instead of public.  They need to be in public for production mode (ie on the web server) so you do an asset precompile as part of your deploy process, which copies them into public.  Feels like a B*llache but it keeps your public folder clean.